# How to format maths equations to display correctly

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I am trying to find the list of Mathjax/Latex instructions on how to type equations and symbols so they display correctly on the site. ie. $2^2$ rather than 2^2

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  This is the reference guide for formatting equations using mathjax on MSE.

Comment: Thanks. When I do the formula's however, if it is large the equation looks very small on the screen. Do you know if there is a way to make it display larger, or just to normal scale?

Comment: If you use this form: \$\$type equation here\$\$, it will enlarge the formula and center it on a new line.  For example, using the single dollar sign you get this: $\int\limits_0^1 x\ dx$ and using double dollar signs you get:  $$\int\limits_0^1 x\ dx$$  Hopefully this answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to waste anytime you can press the edit button of any post that has an equation with the feature you need.

Copy paste the latex  code and play around with it to know what commands do. That way you won't forget them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to LaTeX and need a slower approach to learning it, Here's a link to a playlist of youtube videos that introduces you to using LaTeX.

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1D4EAB31D3EBC449